# Oauth 2.0 for PHP for beginners

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

please advice. if I need to post this somewhere but I really need your help guys. I have this assignment project that needs to be done and it requires oauth2. unfortunately I am very new to this oauth thing. Im the noobest of all the noobs. , I been reading this [site](http://oauth.net/). the problem is that this looks like it requires intermediate knowledge about oauth, and Im having a hard time following on it, can anyone give me some links or books about oauth2 that can be used by beginners who is new to this oauth thing. Currently Im using a framework Laravel and I tried this [package](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). But the configuration are confusing. Please, if you have any blogs, tutorials or books you can share that will help a noob like me, I will be very happy. I don't want to use this oauth thing without understanding everything properly.

```
'grant_types' => array(

        'authorization_code' => array(
            'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AuthCode',
            'access_token_ttl' => 3600,
            'auth_token_ttl'   => 3600,
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password',
            'access_token_ttl' => 604800,
            'callback'         => function ($username, $password) {

                $credentials = array(
                    'email' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                );

                $valid = Auth::validate($credentials);

                if (!$valid) {
                    return false;
                }

                return Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials)->id;
            }
        ),

        'refresh_token' => array(
            'class'                 => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\RefreshToken',
            'access_token_ttl'      => 3600,
            'refresh_token_ttl'     => 604800,
            'rotate_refresh_tokens' => false,
        ),

    ),
```

Comment: just wanna shared http://oauthbible.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to understand the Protocol Flow.

## Protocol Flow

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+
```

The following steps are involved as under:

A. The client requests authorization from the resource owner.

B. The client receives an authorization grant which is a credential representing the resource owner's
    authorization

C. The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
        authorization server and presenting the authorization grant.

D. The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
        the authorization grant, and if valid issues an access token.

E. The client requests the protected resource from the resource
        server and authenticates by presenting the access token.

F. The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
        serves the request.

To have a proper working may read and use [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Hi thanks for the guides. Just wanna ask if im the one giving the access token, how do I generate an access token then, is it just a random?

Comment: Read the OAuth Specifications